# cp -r <Folder Name> .<Folder Name>

Tags: linux, cp, dot-files

I run the command `cp -r <Folder Name> .<Folder Name>`. It have done something, but I cannot find it.

Example:

```
cp -r Agent .Agent.old    # (There is a dot symbol on the 2nd folder name)
```

Comment: since the new directory starts with a dot, it is hidden. You would be able to see it with `ls -a`

Comment: Please add a more descriptive title

Comment: `cp -r` is a vendor unique, do not use it, but rather `cp -R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing the file name with a dot (`.`) is usually considered as hidden files. This folder copying should have done in the same way.

try to list hidden items by.

```
ls -la .Agent.old
```